# Finding different characters in strings of different lengths

Tags: python

I have some code to find the differences between strings. At the moment it works for strings of the same length, but I am trying to get it to work for strings of different length. How can I do this

I added in a new variable `longest_seq` to try and work around this but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
ref_seq = "pandabears"
map_seq = "pondabear"
longest_seq = map_seq

if len(ref_seq) > len(map_seq):
    longest_seq == ref_seq


for i in range(len(longest_seq)):
    if ref_seq[i] != map_seq[i]: 
        print i, ref_seq[i], map_seq[i]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what it means to find "the differences" between two strings? One common way of computing this is the edit distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance. Your current code looks like it is printing characters if they differ at a specific spot.

Comment: @kingkupps Printing characters that differed at a specific spot is what I am trying to do. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
def different_characters(reference, target):
    # So we don't accidentally index the shorter string past its ending
    ending = min(len(reference), len(target))

    for i in range(ending):
        if reference[i] != target[i]:
            print(i, reference[i], target[i])

    longer_str = reference if len(reference) > len(target) else target
    for i in range(ending, len(longer_str)):
        print(i, longer_str[i], '<empty>')


different_characters('pandabears', 'pondabear')
```

Which would print:

```
1 a o
9 s <empty>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2, you can use `itertools.izip` for this:

```
from itertools import izip

for i, j in izip(ref_seq, map_seq):
    if i != j: 
        print i, j
```

Output:

```
a o
```

In Python 3, you can use the built-in `zip` function:

```
for i, j in zip(ref_seq, map_seq):
    if i != j: 
        print(i, j)
```

`zip` exists in Python 2, but `itertools.izip` is recommended because it generates the tuples at demand (in every iteration it generates a new tuple) rather than building all of them at once, in Python 3, `zip` does what `itertools.izip` does in Python 2.

Comment: how can I edit my code to make it work on different length strings though?

Comment: @wilberox What should happen for different length strings? `zip` will take care of the _taking the shortest length string_ problem.